# If $k_{1}$ and $k_{2}$ are $4$ digit numbers . number of ways of forming $k_{1}$ and $k_{2}$

Tags: combinatorics

If $k_{1}$ and $k_{2}$ are $4$ digit numbers . find the number of ways of forming  $k_{1}$ and $k_{2}$ so that $k_{2}$ can be

subtracted from $k_{1}$ without borrowing at any stage

could some help me with this, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every digit of $k_1$ should be greater than or equal to $k_2$.

Number of ways of choosing will be $(^{10}C_2+10)$.

The thousandth digit will be chosen from $\{1,..,9\}$ instead of $\{0,1,...9\}$.

No of ways to choose thousandth digit will be $(^9C_2+9)$

Hence total number of ways is

$$(^9C_2+9)\cdot(^{10}C_2+10)\cdot(^{10}C_2+10)\cdot(^{10}C_2+10)$$

Answer (score 1):

We start by asking a simpler question: If $x$ and $y$ are chosen at random from $\{0,1,2, \dots ,9\}$, what is the probability that $x \le y$?  To answer this, note that
$$\Pr(x<y) + \Pr(x=y) + \Pr(y < x)= 1$$
We see easily that $\Pr(x=y) = 1/10$, and by symmetry, $\Pr(x<y) = \Pr(y<x)$, so
$$2 \Pr(x<y) + 1/10 = 1$$
Therefore $\Pr(x<y) = 9/20$, and $\Pr(x \le y) = 9/20 + 1/10 = 11/20$.

Similarly, we can show that if $x$ and $y$ are chosen at random from $\{1,2,3, \dots ,9\}$ then $\Pr(x \le y) = 5/9$.

So if we have two four-digit numbers $x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4$  and $y_1 y_2 y_3 y_4$ in decimal notation, the probability that $x_i \le y_i$ for $i=1,2,3,4$ is
$$\frac{5}{9} \times \left( \frac{11}{20} \right)^3 \approx 0.09243$$